# Can I alter the view using same view inside the query

Tags: mysql, database, view

I've already a view called base view. Now I used the same base view to alter the base view. And it shows m error. Can I do that?

```
alter view base as 
select t2.*, t1.roll_no,t1.name,t1.phone,t1.email 
from base t2 
inner join users_domain t1 
    on t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
order by user_id 
limit 30
```

And it shows the error below. Please do help

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'exams.base' doesn't exist
>   ERROR: 
>   No query specified

Comment: A view can't refer to itself like that. You are changing the view that is referenced in the view. Edit your question and show the original definition of the base view. If you want it to produce a different result, alter the base view to produce it, or create a new view that references the base view

Comment: create view base as select t2.*, t1.roll_no,t1.name,t1.phone,t1.email from base t2 inner join users_domain t1 on t2.user_id=t1.user_id order by user_id limit 30\G;
this is the original view

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question and add it there.